# Having multiple players on a stage actionscript 3.0 php MySQL

Tags: php, dynamic, actionscript

Sorry for the confusing title, wasn't exactly sure how to word it. I've been following a tutorial for an interactive dynamic flash Actionscript 3.0 game which communicates with php and MySQL to remember certain information about each user. It first sends a request tot he php file getsessionvars.php , which returns values that can be used by the flash game to retireve user information. Basically here is all of the important code, starting from the actionscript:

```
    stop();
    // Assign a variable name for our URLVariables object
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    // Build the varSend variable
    // Be sure you place the proper location reference to your PHP config file here
    var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("getsessionvars.php");
    varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    varSend.data = variables;
    // Build the varLoader variable
    var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
    varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    variables.myRequest = "bringit";
    // Send the data to the php file
    varLoader.load(varSend);
    // When the data comes back from PHP we access it here    
    function completeHandler(event:Event):void{

        var idVar = event.target.data.id_var;
        var userNameVar = event.target.data.uname_var;
        var passVar = event.target.data.upass_var;
        var resultStatus = event.target.data.my_result;
        var coordX=event.target.data.coordx;
        var coordY=event.target.data.coordy;
        if (resultStatus == "no_session"){
           gotoAndStop("no_session");
        } else if (resultStatus == "no_exist"){
           gotoAndStop("no_exist");
        } else if (resultStatus == "all_good"){
           userid_txt.text = idVar;
           username_txt.text = userNameVar;
           password_txt.text = passVar;
           gotoAndStop(5);
           var other:otherPeople = new otherPeople();
           addChild(other);
           other.x=coordX;
           other.y=coordY;
        }
    }
```

Then to getsessionvars.php:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
    $id = ""; // Initialize $id var
    $username = ""; // Initialize $username var
    $password = ""; // Initialize $password var
    if (isset($_POST['myRequest']) && $_POST['myRequest'] == "bringit"){

        $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $log_id);
        $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $log_username);
        $password = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $log_password);

        // Check database to see if the id is related to this password
        include_once("connect.php");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO online ('id','player','xpos','ypos') VALUES('','{$username}','10','30')");
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND username='$username' LIMIT 1");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        $sqla=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online");
            echo "my_result=all_good&id_var=$id&uname_var=$username&upass_var=$password&coordx=30&coordy=50";
    }// close inital if condition
    ?>
```

My question is: How can i make it so that multiple users can appear on the screen at the same time? As you can notice, I've already attempted to try to store the coordinates of the player when they first log in into a MySQL Database and then was hoping to update that information every time the character moves, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your game is slow and turn based, you're heading down the wrong path altogether. 
What you need for simultaneous multiplayer games is a socket server, like SmartFox server or ElectroTank Server.

They guys at electro tank put together a very very good book on the topic:
[http://www.amazon.com/ActionScript-Multiplayer-Games-Virtual-Worlds/dp/0321643364](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321643364)

You should get the book and give it a read. It covers setting up a server and how to make your flash implementations work well with the server driving the updates.